# Is "actioned" a valid word?

Tags: single-word-requests, is-it-a-word

I've just, without much fore thought, used the word "actioned" in the following (example) context, and am now wondering if it's valid (upon a re-read I've decided I don't like the way it sounds, hence the question).

> 1000 emails needed some kind of action, 800 of which were **actioned** by the team while the remaining 200 were escalated.

I can think of (what I feel is) a better word to replace "actioned" in this case - either "processed" and "completed" should do it - and my spell checker doesn't like "actioned", so I'm wondering if the word is valid? If it is, is my above example a valid usage?

Comment: You can't action emails, you can only [action on asks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/08/18/9873193.aspx). (^_^)

Comment: Fore thought? Forethought?

Comment: I've heard this word twice as a verb only today, both in British English. I've never heard it in AmE.

Comment: Not in my universe it ain't. ***800 of which the team acted on and 200 of which were escalated.*** geesus.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This use of "action" as a verb is very common in business contexts, so it's very hard to argue it's *invalid*, but as both your reaction and Robusto's indicate, many people find it awkward, jarring or just plain ugly; for this reason you may wish to avoid using it (although in an internal report in the sort of company where people talk like that, it would be entirely appropriate to do so...).

Other possible replacements:

- taken care of
- dealt with
- carried out
- acted on
- performed
- processed

Comment: Ah, I think you've hit the nail on the head here - essentially it's not in common usage, except as management-speak. In which case, I shall continued to try and avoid using it; just need to teach my fingers not to type it when I'm not looking...

Comment: bullfrog answer. it is in common usage, is neither awkward, jarring or ugly. It is just a word.

Comment: @aaa90210: That's a matter of opinion :-) You're right it's in common use - that's a fact - hence why I said it's not invalid. But it's also a fact that lots of people do find it ugly, and if you want those people not to find your writing ugly, then you may want to avoid it. Just because you're not one of those people doesn't mean they don't exist ;-)

Comment: Business English may be the worst definition of what valid English is. The people sprouting it have exactly the wrong agenda (marketing as opposed to facts, trying to sound sophisticated). E.g. ["Leverage" used as a verb](http://this.isfluent.com/2010/1/are-you-stupid-enough-to-use-leverage-as-a-verb), ["Incentivize"](https://thedeathofreason.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/i-will-kill-the-next-person-that-says-incentivize), and ["Revert" used to mean "reply"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10143/can-revert-be-used-as-a-synonym-of-reply).

Answer (score 13):

English has a long history of turning nouns into verbs, but this one feels just awkward.

I'd suggest "acted on" instead of "actioned" here, or some other word or construction.

You could say something like:

> 1,000 emails needed some kind of action, 800 of which were tackled by the team while the remaining 200 were escalated.

**Tackle** in this case means to

> make determined efforts to deal with (a problem or difficult task) : *police have launched an initiative to tackle rising crime.*

Speaking of that, you could use "dealt with" in place of "actioned" there as well.

Answer (score 9):

Since escalating a problem is also an action, I'd hunt for
a word or phrase that describes what the team did with or about
those messages that were NOT escalated.   In the absence of a better
choice, I'd use "resolved", or "handled".

Answer (score 5):

I would guess that "action" as a verb is a [back-formation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation) from "[actionable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/actionable)", which *is* a word a long history. The formation would arise from this perfectly reasonable thought: if something is "actionable", that means you must be able to "action" it, right?

However, *action* as a verb is not listed in any of the major published dictionaries I looked in, nor are there any examples of *actioned* in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/12016910).

Interestingly, in the [Google ngram for 'actioned'](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=actioned&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), there was a large surge of usage in the mid-19th century that dropped to a trickle until a new surge starting in the early 1980s. Most of the 19th-century examples seem to be related to horses ("Before dismissing the horse stock, we must not omit to notice a fine-**actioned** grey colt, bred by Lord Hastings") and guns ("Patent double-**actioned** high-pressure sky-blue revolvers").

[image: ngram for 'actioned']

Answer (score 1):

Business jargon is often awkward in everyday speech. This is certainly a prime example.

The best commonplace verb to replace *actioned* in this sense would probably be the good ol' utilitarian **handled**. It may not sound as exciting as *tackled*, but it's simply the fact rather than the embellishment.

I also wouldn't recommend *processed*, although at first glance that seems a good substitute, because *processed* could simply mean *filed* or otherwise not really handled. One can process a form without taking a single action requested on the form.

Answer (score 0):

To action is also legal term - if you actioned someone, you took them to court

But I did find actioned here: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/actioned

> to put into effect; take action
>   concerning matters decided at the
>   meeting cannot be actioned until the
>   following week

Comment: Hmmm... I think it's clear that whatever the intended meaning is, "take the e-mails to court" probably isn't it...

Comment: Why was it important to downvote this without a comment as to why?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this term might be a North American term, hence why it seems to be rejected by my spell checker. 
I have used this term on one or two occasions, but I might have heard it used in some U.S programs over the years.

Comment: I'm presuming you don't normally speak American English?

Comment: I've never heard it in AmE (native speaker), only in uses in British English--both spoken and written and in a business/administrative context.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty with answering this question is that there are two different strands to it.  *Actionable* is a word with a respectable history, in both British and American English: unfortunately, in this sense it is a technical legal term, meaning "an action at law will lie". This is not the same as *illegal*, but is similar to *tortious*; e.g. "Firing people because of their age is actionable".     [IANAL]

There is another sense, 'able to be acted upon'.  This is much more American than British, but is in the OED with citations from 1913 (as opposed to 1601 for the legal sense).  It is not much used formally because of the potential for confusion, but certainly can be taken as a basis for the back-formation of 'to action'.  The word is, however, ugly and probably redundant: I have never seen a use that could not be better handled by *act*; "800 of them were acted on by the team."

So you can reasonably defend yourself if accused of employing a non-existent word, but in practice it's probably better to find an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think actioned should be considered as a valid word, atleast that's my conclusion from the example you gave us.

Consider the following sentences.

> 1000 emails needed `action`, 800 of which got `action` from the team.

.

> 1000 emails needed `processing`, 800 of which were `processed` by the team.

.

> 1000 emails needed `tackling`, 800 of which were `tackled` by the team.

.

> 1000 emails needed `completion`, 800 of which were `completed` by the team.

I hope you see the pattern here, `actioned` would be said in the following case:

> 1000 emails needed `actioning`, 800 of which were `actioned` by the team.

that either proves `actioned` is not a valid word or raises another question, is actioning a valid word?

Comment: Agree: "is actioning a valid word?" - it seems to be quite common.

Comment: Sorry.  I can't count your ENGLISH answer as credible when you spell "at least" as one word.

Comment: Kitty's criticism about a typo is secondary; this answer doesn't provide any referenced support (or any support at all, really) for acceptability or otherwise.