# Usage of phrase "revert back"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, adverbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can 'revert' be used as a synonym of 'reply'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10143/can-revert-be-used-as-a-synonym-of-reply)

Is it correct English to refer to replying to someone or giving feedback as "reverting back"? People in my workplace are using that term more and more. It sounds completely wrong to me.

Here are some examples:

> - We will investigate and revert back as soon as possible.
> - Will reschedule and revert back!
> - Please let me know who will be able to go and who won’t by COB tomorrow so that I can revert back to her.

Comment: Related: [Can 'revert' be used as a synonym of 'reply'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10143/can-revert-be-used-as-a-synonym-of-reply)

Comment: I'd say it's a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 6):

I have observed this usage among speakers of Indian English, wherein it appears to be normal.

AFAIK it is unknown in other varieties of English.

Comment: I'd have to dispute the use of the word 'normal' and replace it with 'common', normal implies some kind of acceptance to me ;) "Revert" in place of "Reply" is just plain wrong and needs to be stamped out!

Comment: On what grounds, Lazarus, do you presume to say what is "right" or "wrong" in Indian English?

Comment: I appreciate that I hadn't noticed your explicit reference to Indian English so it may be wrong of me to say that it's wrong in that context. That said, I can't seem to find any official statement regarding "Indian English" as a formal language, the documentation I can find seems to list Hindi and English as the common languages of the Indian Union, not Indian English. Accepting that "Revert to me" is a local idiom in India does not make it correct English but I concede your point to avoid further pedantry.

Comment: You probably won't find an official document mentioning British English, American English, Canadian English, Australian English, New Zealand English, Singapore English, Jamaican English, South African English or any other varieties in their respective polities. So what?