# What other ways are there to write officially "let us know"?

Tags: synonyms

Synonyms required. Phrases are preferred.

Comment: Context required.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep us informed...
We'd like to be kept up to date...
Please contact us as soon as you know more...
Please keep in touch...
Drop us a line if anything changes...
We are eager to know more...

Answer (score 0):

"Kindly revert back to us as soon as you can" is what comes to mind

Comment: Do you mean refer, and not revert?

Comment: It is quite common in Namibia and especially India, but from what I saw now, it is not correct English, see this discussion: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34816/usage-of-phrase-revert-back